# how to compare n multiple sentences which are in array and get the common words using php using array_intersect and store the common words in an array

Tags: php, arrays, words

Hi friends am trying to compare n sentences in an array and get the common words which are present in more than one sentence.
Here is sample

```
 $cars=("hello how","hello when","when you came",........,n sentences);
```

array_intersect is used to compare 2 or 3 arrays which have exactly common words in all the three can anyone help me with these

Comment: explode the sentences using explode() and then try array_intersect

Comment: array_intersect gives when the same word matches in all the sentence but i want if it matches in any two sentences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$cars = array_filter(
            array_count_values(
                   array_merge(
                        ...array_map(
                              function($x) { return array_unique(explode(' ', $x));},
                              $cars))), 
            function($x) { return $x > 1; });
print_r($cars);
```

Step by step

1. Explode strings and save only unique words
2. Merge all arrays
3. Count frequency for each word
4. Get words that exist more than one time

[**demo**](https://eval.in/926613)

Comment: its showing error when running file locally 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.' in C:\xampp\htdocs\youtubeplaylist\cars.php on line 5

Comment: What is PHP version ?

Comment: 5.5.38 php version

Comment: change the answer above

Comment: It works fine for PHP 5.6 and above that is not rare for now :)

Comment: is there any way i can store the only words in array without count like a normal array